# Kia Sorrento 2006 making vibration on gear change

Tags: vibration, kia, sorrento

I have Kia Sorrento 2006 model car. Whenever I change the gear especially from Parking to Reverse the car vibrates. I can also feel little vibration while changing the gear from neutral to driving. What could be the issue? What shall I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Check the clutch setting of u r vehicle if after pressing clutch pedal some time cluctch not disengaged properly due that vibration can come in engine

Comment: It's automatic car. There is no clutch in it.